# Can a question which is put on hold still be reviewed in the first posts queue?

Tags: discussion, bug, review

Mere curiosity:

How come this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/85738) is reviewed 2 minutes ago (at the time of writing this question), by appearing in the first posts queue, whereas it was put on hold  14 hours ago?

This is not the first time it happens (and always with the same user). I noticed a similar case on Information Security website when I was active there 2 years ago and always with the same user (not this user on CodeReview though). So I am wondering if there is any bug which some smart users are exploiting.

(originally, this question was posted on CodeReview Meta, but since there was no feedback, I moved it to here)

EDIT (today October 23rd):

Right now, this is the nth time this happened:

There was no new post (question or answer) since I logged and reviewed the last ones. But the user  was the third on both review queues (first pasts and late answers), and now [he is the first in both of them](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review) and me second while [his review history](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120114/sam-onela?tab=activity) shows the last time he reviewed anything was 15 hours ago.

For example, for the first posts queue: how come the last visible question that is posted is [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178615/service-worker-fetch-handler-with-promise-race-code) which I reviewed before but the user just logged in and he appears the head of the queue while his review history dates back to 15 hours ago.

As I said, this is not the first time this happens.

Comment: "Sam Onela reviewed this **15 hours ago**" - 15 hours, not 2 minutes

Comment: Well, I said I moved the question from CodeReview Meta website to here. I did a copy/paste. I asked it since almost 20 hours ago. @ShadowWizard

Comment: Could it be that the reviewer opened a tab with the review (while the question was still open), then waited 14 hours and came back and reviewed it?

Comment: No that can not be so since he behaves so almost on a daily basis

Answer (score 2):

Don't think it's a bug.

First post review is meant to review user's first post and evaluate it. If the question is off topic, the reviewer should flag/vote to close it. However, same way, if the question is already closed but is on topic, and the reviewer has enough rep, probably they're expected to cast a reopen vote from the review.

Comment: I would love to think so. However only that user has been able, so far, to face such scenarios. He is also able to review already reviewed and upvoted late answers which were posted many days ago; he also reviews mysteriously late answers which do not exist (I've been told that concerns deleted late answers, but that is really impossible: it occurs in front of my eyes while I do not see any posted then removed late answer). A question which is put on hold  can appear, IMHO, only in the "Reopen Votes" queue. I suspect there is a bug around here.  Thank you for the feedback