# The ghost review

Tags: bug, review

The last post I reviewed in the Late Answers queue dates back to 9 hours ago (by the time I am writing this). I was appearing on the head of the queue until a moment ago when a user just logged in and appeared, mysteriously, on the head of [this same queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review). But the problem is that there is no late answer posted either before, or after he logged in, and his review history shows the last post he reviewed was [16 hours ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120114/sam-onela?tab=activity) (by the time this question is written).

My question: where is this late answers that I did not see? Deleted by the owner? No, it is an impossible scenario as I have been online and nothing like that happened.

The user appears on the head of that queue whenever he finds himself not on that position.

I recently posted a question about this exact thing but I deleted it after a user said it must be a late answer deleted by its owner (which scenario I did not believe in as it simply did not occur).

This scenario also is related to the one I described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302329/can-a-question-which-is-put-on-hold-still-be-reviewed-in-the-first-posts-queue).

Is there a bug which some users exploit? The user in question even reviews old posts which are post on hold several hours ago as elements of the First Posts queue.

I also noticed 2 years ago, a different user behaving exactly the same way on Information Security website where I am no longer active.

Comment: He is exploiting a [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268592) that exists on some queues, to post reviews to older review tasks. It's currently by-design that this grace period exists. We *were* looking into if there was a way to prevent the abusive reviews, but apparently that never resulted in anything.

Answer (score 3):

As [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) mentions in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302481/the-ghost-review#comment983866_302481):

> He is exploiting a [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268592/365152) that exists on some queues, to post reviews to older review tasks. It's currently by-design that this grace period exists. We were looking into if there was a way to prevent the abusive reviews, but apparently that never resulted in anything.